# Symfony2 - Doctrine2 Association Class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having trouble converting a ManyToMany relationship to utilize an Association Class. I have 2 classes `Asset` and `User` Currently I have a ManyToMany on `Asset#users` and `User#Assets`

I needed to add some extra data so I now have 3 classes `Assets` `Users` and `Associations`. `Asset#users` and `User#assets` are now a `OneToMany` with `Associations` and `Associations#Asset` and `Association#User` are a `ManyToOne`

In my previous implementation I had a `FormType` for `Assets` with the following:

```
->add('users', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppUserBundle:User',
            'query_builder' => function($er) use($username){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.username != ?1')
                    ->setParameter(1,$username);
            },
            'expanded' => "true", 
            "multiple" => "true"    
        ))
```

This would display a list of users (except for the current user), and any user already associated would be checked.

With my new Schema I get the error `Found entity of type App\UserBundle\Entity\User on association App\AssetBundle\Entity\Asset#users, but expecting App\AssetBundle\Entity\UserAssociation`

This makes sense as it is now looking for the `UserAssociation` and not the `User`

I need the form to display All Users (minus the logged in user) and show which users are already Associated with the Asset. I am lost at how to do this.